# Is there a way to auto-baseline-shift a line to the top of the largest inline object?

Tags: adobe-indesign, typography

Indesign aligns inline objects to the bottom. Is there a way to make it so inserting an object inline will make everything go to the top instead? I can manually accomplish this with baseline shift, but I'm looking for something I can attribute to a paragraph style that will responsively change based on the size of inline objects.

[image]

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GDSE! What do you expect will happen with the next line of text? Should it continue below the anchored objects or go through them?

Comment: Ah, great question! I should clarify that the next line would continue below the anchored object.

Comment: You’re thinking about this backwards, I think – it’s the object, not the text, you should shift. It’s very rare that I use the inline positioning settings for anchored objects, but I think you can choose where to align the inline positioning. Then you don’t have to fiddle with baseline shifts that have to take into account how tall the anchored objects all are.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, the problem using the anchored object options is that for inline objects the only setting is "Y Offset" which is relative to the bottom of the object. So to snap to the top, you need to do it manually taking each object's height into account. "Above Line" or "Custom" doesn't work in this case because they move the anchored objects out of the text flow.

Comment: @Wolff You’re right – I misremembered. I thought there was a reference point option for inline positioning as well, but there isn’t. You can use Custom positioning to put it in the right place and then use text wrap to jump the object – but then there’s the annoying bug (which sadly Adobe have no plans to fix because it requires too much code rewriting) that text wrap on non-flowed anchored elements only applies to lines _after_ the element’s containing line, so that’ll move the rest of the paragraph, but not the current line. :-/

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, it's annyoing, but I don't consider it a bug. Try to imagine that it was possible. The object would push text before itself, forcing *itself* to move forward. That would leave place above it forcing it to move back again. Endless loop.

Comment: @Wolff I don’t see why. If you give an anchored object a custom position, that should always remain the same. If you also give it text wrap, the text that it collides with should jump out of the way. It should never be possible for it to move itself. This is how it works in CSS as well, which is similar in theory: floating an image located in the middle of a line of text won’t result in that line of text running through the image and then the following lines wrapping around it – all lines, both before and after, will wrap around it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, I made a half-hearted attempt at explaining it [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/134275/84899). I might overlook something, but if you allow an anchored object to move the text on the same line and before, it could move the anchor. Even if the anchor's position isn't relative to the text it could be forced to jump to the next text frame. And then back and forth forever.

Comment: @Wolff True, you’d have to deal with the possibility of frame jumping (which isn’t an issue in the CSS parallel, of course). That could be worked around, though, and it wouldn’t be too hard. It could function similar to keep options: if an anchor does not fit into the current frame when factoring in the space cleared by the anchored object, then the anchor (and the object) move to the next frame and stay there. It only becomes an infinite loop if you recalculate once the object is moved and then move the text back, which can be easily avoided.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116446/discussion-between-wolff-and-janus-bahs-jacquet).

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell show you a fully automated way to do this, but I have something better than using baseline shift: simply *move* the inline objects.

What happens when you paste an object into a text frame isn't really that it "makes things go to the bottom". Anchored objects by default simply sits on the same line as the letters. The anchored object must stay inside the text frame, so the whole text line moves down to make room for the anchored objects.

[image]

A way to make the anchored objects hang below the baseline is to first drag them down too much to make the text move all the way to the top and then select each one of them and set their top Y-coordinate to match the top Y-coordinate of the text frame. (Sadly the anchored objects won't snap to the top of the text frame.)

[image]

If you enter more text in the text frame it will go through the anchored objects. This can be fixed by applying *Jump object* text wrapping to the anchored objects.

[image]

Comment: This gets me 80% of the way there. Thank you! 

I guess what I'm looking for is a way to make an object have Anchored Object Options allow me to set the Inline Y Offset to "-auto." That really would do it.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't. If we know what you need this for, perhaps we could find a totally different way to do it.

Comment: The purpose would be for questions that have inline art that all have different heights and widths.

Comment: Can the line height (the distance to the next paragraph with inline graphics) be constant? In that case you could paste your graphics into a taller frame (as tall as the tallest graphics or more) which has an Object Style that places it correctly in all instances. I can add it to the answer if you are interested.

Comment: Unfortunately no. If an object is smaller, the publisher wants the line to be smaller. For instance, one line would have a) and b), the next line might have c) and d), and the art for all four may have different heights.